# JPA & Ebean ORM: Empty collection is not empty

Tags: orm, jpa

I've started switching over a project from hand-written JDBC ORM code to Ebeans.  So far it's been great; Ebeans is light and easy to use.

However, I have run into a crippling issue: when retrieving a one-to-many list which should be empty there is actually one element in it.  This element looks to be some kind of proxy object which has all null fields, so it breaks code which loops through the collection.

I've included abbreviated definitions here:

```
@Entity
class Store {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="store",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    List<StoreAlbum> storeAlbums = new LinkedList<StoreAlbum>();
}

@Entity
class StoreAlbum {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(optional=false,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="store_id",nullable=false)
    Store store;
}
```

The ... are where all the standard getters and setters are.  The retrieval code looks like this:

```
Store s = server.find(Store.class)
            .where()
            .eq("store_id",4)
            .findUnique();

Assert.assertEquals("Sprint",s.getStoreName());
Assert.assertEquals(0, s.getStoreAlbums().size());
```

The database is known to contain a 'store' row for "Sprint", and the 'store_album' table does not contain any rows for that store.

The JUnit test fails on the second assertion.  It finds a list with 1 element in it, which is some kind of broken StoreAlbum object.  The debugger shows the object as being of the type "com.lwm.catalogfeed.domain.StoreAlbum$$EntityBean$test@1a5e68a" with null values for all the fields which are declared as nullable=false (and optional=false).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I've turned the SQL debugging on, and noticed that the query is doing a "left outer join" one the store_album table:  
select t0.store_id c0, t0.store_name c1, t0.platform_name c2, t0.dsp_id c3
        , t1.store_id c4, t1.album_id c5, t1.dsp_id c6, t1.pricecode_id c7 
from store t0
left outer join store_album t1 on t1.store_id = t0.store_id  
where t0.store_id = ?  
order by t0.store_id  

  
There must be a way to change this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd post an update on this... I ended up giving up on EBeans and instead switched the implementation over to use MyBatis.  MyBatis is fantastic; the manual is easy to read and thorough.  MyBatis does what you expect it to do.  I got it up and running in no time.

EBeans didn't appear to detect that the join for the associated collection resulted in a bunch of null ids, but MyBatis handled this scenario cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and was able to solve it by adding an identity column to the secondary table (StoreAlbum). I did not investigate the cause but I suppose Ebean needs a primary key on the table in these kind of situations.